# Recursive directory listing using Ruby with Chinese characters in file names

Tags: ruby, file, unicode, directory-listing, cjk

I would like to generate a list of files within a directory. Some of the filenames contain Chinese characters.

eg: [试验].Test.txt

I am using the following code:

```
require 'find'
dirs = ["TestDir"]
for dir in dirs
    Find.find(dir) do |path|
    if FileTest.directory?(path)
    else
        p path
    end
    end
end
```

Running the script produces a list of files but the Chinese characters are escaped (replaced with backslashes followed by numbers). Using the example filename above would produce:

"TestDir/[\312\324\321\351]Test.txt" instead of "TestDir/[试验].Test.txt".

How can the script be altered to output the Chinese characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby needs to know that you are dealing with unicode in your code. Set appropriate character encoding using KCODE, as below:

```
$KCODE = 'utf-8'
```

I think utf-8 is good enough for chinese characters.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is more elegant and doesn't require 'find.' It produces a list of files (but not directories) in whatever the working directory is (or whatever directory you put in).

```
Dir.entries(Dir.pwd).each do |x|
  p x.encode('UTF-8') unless FileTest.directory?(x)  
end
```

And to get a recursive digging down one level use:

```
Dir.glob('*/*').each do |x|
  p x.encode('UTF-8') unless FileTest.directory?(x)  
end
```

I'm sure there is a way to get it to go all the way down but `Dir.glob('**/*')` will go through the whole file system if I remember right.